# Continuous data duplication when item is inserted into React js Array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Data is being duplicated when item is inserted into React js Array state,

```
console.log(newData)
```

outputs a single object, while

```
console.log(data)
```

outputs continuous duplicate of

```
console.log(newData)
```

How do i fix it

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const addData = (newData) => {
       
        console.log(newData)
        setData(prevData => [...prevData, newData]);
        console.log(data)
        
    };

    useEffect(() => {
          axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${pid}`)
            .then((res) => {
              addData(res.data); // Update the state directly with the response data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });
       
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "outputs continuous duplicate of `console.log(newData)`"? Can you give some examples maybe of what the logs are showing

Comment: you need to add dependency array in `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

```
    useEffect(()=> {
   axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${pid}`)
            .then((res) => {
              addData(res.data); // Update the state directly with the response data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });
}, [data]) // Add the [data] (The dependency array) to say that we want this renders only when this var changes
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const addData = (newData) => {
        console.log(newData)
        setData(prevData => [...prevData, newData]);
        console.log(data)
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      // even if useEffect is called again, you will only execute code, if your state array is empty
      if(data.length === 0){
        axios
        .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/products/${pid}`)
        .then((res) => {
           cosole.log("res.data", res.data);
          // make sure res.data is an array
          addData(res.data); // Update the state directly with the response data
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          // always use console.error() to print the errors
          console.error(err);
        });
      }
    }, []); 
//  add your dependency here, I kept it empty, 
// because I assume, you want to add the data in the first render only
```